# iOS Layout frame issue

Tags: iphone, view

I have a view which perfectly fits all other screens except iPhone 4s and below.At first I implemented scrollview for the view in iPhone 4s and below, but now scroll view has to be removed and the only go is to check weather the device is below iPhone 5 and adjust the frame so that content fits in screen. I have checked and tried updating frame of the view for models below iPhone 5.This doesn't work and the frame doesn't get updated as I am using auto layout. In short if the model is below iPhone 5 i want to update my y of the origin of the frame so that view is completely seen. Any methods ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit difficult to understand your question.

If you set the bottom layout constraint of the scroll view to be in line with the bottom layout guide of the main view, the scroll view should resize to fit the screen regardless of the model of phone.

It sounds like your issue is not with the scroll view frame but with the size of its content.  I am not entirely sure though what exactly the issue is... i.e. what you are seeing versus what you would like to see.